# HTML table semantics: <thead> with multiple <tr>

Tags: html, html-table, semantic-markup, screen-readers

If i define a `<thead>` like this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Category 1</th>
    <th colspan=2>Category 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sub-cat 1</th>
    <th>Sub-cat 2</th>
    <th>Sub-cat 3</th>
    <th>Sub-cat 4</th>
    <th>Sub-cat 5</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Does this structure semantically separate the categories/sub-categories correctly?

I know that visually it will look good, but I am unsure how this would look to a screen reader or to W3C specs in general.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Browsers can use `thead`, `tbody`, `tfooter` to enable scrolling of the table body independently of the header and footer. Also, when printing a large table that spans multiple pages, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfooter` elements can enable the table header and footer to be printed at the top and bottom of each page. See this for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Comment: does that mean there is no distinction of columns and sub-columns of categories? it is purely a structural thing?  ..also i dont rely on w3schools for information.

Comment: Yes exactly. This no relation with columns.